# How to modify the self data of subclass from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subclass

What I want to do is like:

```
class myclass(DataFrame):
    ...
    def add(self, series): # series is a Series
        self = self.append(series)
```

I know the 'self = self.append(series)' is not correct, but how to correct it? Cause unlike list in python, append operation in DataFrame does not modify itself, so how can I update itself with append?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a new sub-class you can just add your own methods to `pd.DataFrame()` by [monkey-patching](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15/faq.html#adding-features-to-your-pandas-installation).

**Set up**

```
import pandas as pd

def vertical_add(self, series):
    return pd.concat([self, series])

def horizontal_add(self, series):
    return pd.concat([self, series], axis=1)

pd.DataFrame.vertical_add = vertical_add
pd.DataFrame.horizontal_add = horizontal_add
```

**Define some data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
series = pd.Series(np.arange(10,16))
```

**Apply new method(s)**

```
df.vertical_add(series)
df.horizontal_add(series)
```